# How to calculate text position on the PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox, fontbox

I get some data from the web browser and should create a PDF document. I get the data looks like the following:

```
rectangle for the text placement;
font size
font name
text
```

The problem is I can't understand how I can calculate the text position on the PDF document correctly. The text in the browser looks like that
[image: 1], 
but the text in my Pdf looks like that
[image: 2]

I get the `X` coord as I get it from the browser, but the text is shifted  on the left. I read that the each glyph has a bounding box and placed the by the center. 
I tried to calculate my x,y by the following way:

```
public Rectangle2D.Float calculatePosition(PDFont font, float fontSize, float x, float y, String text, float pageWidth, float pageHeight) {
    final PDFontDescriptor fontDescriptor = font.getFontDescriptor();

    final float ascent = fontDescriptor.getAscent();
    final float descent = fontDescriptor.getDescent();
    final float textHeight = (ascent - descent) * fontSize / 1000 + textRise;
    final float textWidth = font.getStringWidth(text) * fontSize / 1000;
    return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, textWidth, textHeight);
}
```

Can anyone help me, how to calculate x,y position?

Comment: 1 unit in PDF coordinates = 1/72 inch if the PDF is rendered at 72dpi which is "100%" in PDFBox PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I know that, and in my data that is coming into the method already calculated. For instance, I get x from the browser equals 10px, and I translate it into the PDF manner 10 * 0.75 = 7.5px, but in the PDF the text position is not equal to the browser, and we see the text is shifted to the right in the  PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I read that each glyph has the bounding box and the start point of the text is not necessarily equal to the 0 of that bounding box. And I can't calculate that delta x coord

Comment: You could either get the glyph path (see the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example and look for `vectorFont.getPath(code)`) and get the bounding box, or you use fontbox to get the HorizontalMetricsTable of the font and get the LeftSideBearing for that gid. To get the gid, use codeToGID().